# Prove or disprove this set equality.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have to prove or disprove this:

$$(A - C) ∩ (C - B) = \emptyset.$$

Can someone show me or guide me on how do I do this? I tried proving this using Venn diagrams, and I think it's false, because we never subtract from $B$. Is that right?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $x\in A-C$ then $x\not\in C,$ but if $x\in C-B$ then $x \in C$

Comment: The "never subtracting form $B$" doesn't matter.  $C\setminus B \subset C$ so $M\cap (C\setminus B) \subset M \cap C$  And as we *did* subtract from $C$ in the $(A-C)$ we have $(A-C)\cap C = \emptyset$.

Comment: $A-C$ contains *NO* parts of $C$ because $C$ was subtracted.  And $C-B$ contains *ONLY* parts of $C$ because things were subtracted *FROM* $C$.  So $(A-C)\cap (C-B)$ contains *no* parts of $C$ but also *only* parts of $C$.  So the only parts that it contains are parts it *doesn't* contain so it contains no parts and is empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The intersection $(A-C)\cap(C-B)$ is empty,

because any element of $A-C$ is not in $C$, and any element of $C-B$ is in $C$,

so there are no elements in $A-C$ and $C-B$.

Answer (score 3):

J. W. Tanner's answer is correct, but just to do it via a Venn diagram:

$A - C$ is region I and region IV

$C - B$ is region III and region V

Since there are no regions in both, $(A - C)\cap(C - B)$ must empty i.e. $\emptyset$

[image]

Comment: I was thinking that a diagram would help, but I'm not so good at drawing; +1

Comment: @J.W.Tanner haha, no worries. I just used MS Paint :P

Answer (score 1):

$\color{magenta}{(A\setminus C)}\cap \color{green}{(C\setminus B)}$

[image]

If *roundsquare* wants to steal this image and and it to his/her excellent answer, s/he has my permission and I will delete this derivative post.

But... colors help.

oh.... and hopefully J.W. Tanner's point is abundantly clear:  $\color{magenta}{(A\setminus C)}$ contains utterly no part of $C$.  (Because $C$ was subtracted) while $\color{green}{(C\setminus B)}$ contains *ONLY* parts of $C$ because everything was subtracted *FROM* $C$.

So the intersect contains no part of $C$ and *only* parts of $C$.  Thus the intersection is empty.