# Prove using set identities

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$,$B$,$C$ be sets. Draw a Venn diagram and color the region $(A−C) \cap (C−B)$. Prove that $(A−C)\cap (C−B)=∅$.

Already done the first part, but the proving part I am stuck at. I have no clue on how to do this. Please show/guide me

[image: Lorem ipsum.]

Comment: cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3575311/prove-or-disprove-this-set-equality)

Comment: My advice when you're stuck on a problem is to start with definitions. In this case, you could start with what $A–C$ mean $A$ without $C$ and then proceed. That's one tip you could follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\begin{align}
x\in (A-C)\cap(C-B)&\iff (x\in A-C)\text{ and }(x\in C-B) \\ 
&\iff (x\in A \text{ and }x\notin C) \text{ and }(x\in C\text{ and }x\notin B)\\ 
&\iff \color{red}{(x\in C\text{ and }x\notin C)}\text{ and }(x\in A\text{ and }x\notin B),
\end{align}$$

which is a $\color{red}{\text{contradiction}}$.

Hence $(A-C)\cap(C-B)=\varnothing $.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- Note that $C - B = C \cap B^c \subseteq C$.
- Note that, for all $c \in C$, $c \not \in A - C$ by definition.

From these, what can you conclude about the intersection? You should be able to conclude the validity of the statement, and fill in the details of the proof.